# vim one-second delay for scrolling with <C-Y>; disabling a plugin's mappings

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

For the past few months I've been experiencing a strange one-second delay when I try to scroll up one line with `<C-Y>`.  There's no such delay with `<C-U>` or `<C-B>`.

I scanned through all my mappings and I believe I've narrowed it down to the [ZenCoding](https://github.com/mattn/zencoding-vim) plugin, which has several normal mode mappings for `<C-Y>` followed by a letter.  Apparently the wait time to press a letter is one second, and if no letter is pressed, it proceeds with the default `<C-Y>` behavior.

In my vimrc, is there a way to either disable all normal mode mappings for a specific plugin, or to reset specific mappings to their default state?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, plugins define mappings starting with `<Plug>`, and check whether the user has already customized it. In such a case, you remap like this:

```
:nmap <F11> <Plug>MappingNameHere
```

However, the ZenCoding plugin seems to define a lot of mappings, where such a scheme would be tedious. Instead, it has a configuration variable that defines the start key. To change this to <kbd>F11</kbd>, for example, put the following into your `~/.vimrc` (or anywhere else before `plugin/zencoding.vim` is sourced):

```
:let g:user_zen_leader_key = '<F11>'
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  I'm going to go with the former method, despite it being tedious, because I only want to change the normal-mode mappings.  Insert-mode `<C-Y>` mappings are fine, because single-line scrolling only works in normal mode.